# Ruby on Rails Tutorial section 10.4.2 test fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

After completing listing [Listing 10.40](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code%3adestroy_tests) and running rspec /spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb, I got 1 failure for section (all other tests in 'destroy' section are passed)

```
describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
  end

  describe "as a non-signed-in user" do
    it "should deny access" do
      delete :destroy, :id => @user
      response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the console output:

```
Failures:
  1) UsersController DELETE 'destroy' as a non-signed-in user should deny access
     Failure/Error: delete :destroy, :id => @user
     undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:66:in `admin_user'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:282:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I can't figure out whether there is an error in the tutorial's code or I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that readers who run into this problem are simply missing the `:destroy` method in the `:authenticate` before filter introduced in [Listing 10.11](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code:authenticate_before_filter). (*Note:* I am the author of the book.)

Comment: See the first line of [Listing 10.41](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code:admin_destroy_before_filter) for the complete filter.

Answer (score 3):

Can't tell for sure, but it seems like this is the part of the tutorial code that's failing

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
```

If nobody is signed in on that page, `current_user` is nil (I assume) and therefore can't have a `admin?` method called.

Try replacing that with

```
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
```

(and replace other current_user logic on the page similarly).

Does that work?

Also, if you comment out this test, does the same test with a logged in user pass?

---

After looking into it more closely, disregard the above: the test is failing because in true TDD-style the test is written before the code. Sot the steps are:

1. Write the test
2. Watch it fail
3. Write the code to make the test pass
4. Watch the test pass

You haven't yet written the code to check is a user is admin. Write the code in section Listing 10.41 in the tutorial, and the test should pass.

However, it might be necessary to put

```
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
end
```

In the before filter (notice we check for a current_user before seeing if he's an admin).

Comment: Can you please clarify where exactly I should replace that, i.e. controller, model ... ? If I comment out that test, everything else is green.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the TDD principle, I just omitted all other spec sections in my question, sorry if that confused you. I've added `current_user` check and now that part seems to work. But I got another failure in line `response.should redirect_to(signin_path)`. For some reason, there is actually a redirect to `root_path` and the last line of `destroy` method of `user` controller is `redirect_to users_path`. I must be missing something.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. `def admin_user` from the `user` controller should be like `redirect_to(signin_path) unless current_user && current_user.admin?`. Now all test pass, thank you.

Comment: The tutorial code actually checks if the user is signed in before checking if he's admin. So you don't need "current_user &&" as above (but it should work nonetheless). It's hard to pinpoint the issue without the code, but check User.authenticate: it should redirect to signin_path on failure.

Comment: I don't think so: if the user isn't and admin (but he's already signed in), you just want to redirect him to root_path with a message saying access in not authorized. On the other hand, if the user isn't signed in at all, THEN (on only then) you want to redirect him to the sign in page. So in my opinion your fix doesn't do what you really want for your application (despite passing the tests).

Comment: User.authenticate should redirect to signin_path on failure according to sessions helper. You could check https://github.com/defeed/sample_app if you have some time for that, I would appreciate this.

Comment: Try this: change the admin_user back to redirect_to(root_path) (because I think that's what it should be. I think the error is the before_filter: add to it so it reads `before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]`. As it is, it doesn't check if a user is signed in before the destroy action, hence your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading that tutorial and I encountered this failing test as well.

Check if you have:

`before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

instead of:

`before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update]`

in `users_controller.rb`